# Jquery AJAX function with $.post not going through, can't find any syntax errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapContent(cv) {
        $(".loading").html("loading-gif").show();
        $.post( "one.php", {contentVar: "cv"},function(data) { 
            $(".loading").html(data).show();
            alert('Info Sent!');
        });
    }
</script>
```

And "one.php"

```
<?php
$contentVar=$_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar == "con1") {
    $row_number = $published_posts;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
else if ($contentVar == "con2") {

}
?>
```

I put the alert in the $.post so I can tell where my script is failing. I recieved alerts at every stage in the script up until $.post ceased to display the alert. Meaning that is where the code is faulted. But from what I can tell there doesn't seem to be any syntax errors, what could be the reason this is not working?

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console. Do you see the request being made to `one.php`? If so, what is the response data?

Comment: Add error handler tO the ajax call. Does it get triggered? How is `swapContent` called? Do you realize you are passing the string `cv` and not the variable `cv`

Comment: no condition is successful in your php code because data is sended `cv` and you are trying to match it with `con1,con2`. so it's not working

Comment: @AlivetoDie noticed that too but OP should still see the *"Info Sent!"* alert

Comment: It's called through a `javacript:onmousedown`, the function `swapContent` is being called however.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, OP would not see it if the server threw an error

Comment: `$.post({...}).fail( function() { console.error(arguments); });`

Comment: Ah ok, so the error is a 404. However, `one.php` and the file this code is running off of `index.php` are both within the same folder. They're both contained within a wordpress theme folder.

Comment: @peterk  try to provide full path there instead of `one.php`. before that check once the permission of `one.php`. change it to 644 and then try first with same code or with full path

Comment: So what is the URL in the network panel? Is it what you expect it to be? Maybe it should be `$.post( "/one.php", {contentVar: cv}, function(){console.log(arguments);}).fail( function() {console.error(arguments);});`

Comment: Seems like something that should ideally be handled by Wordpress' AJAX actions ~ https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! Had to specify the exact location of the file I was trying to post to. Due to the files being within a wordpress theme, I had to specify their location with `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>`

```
$.post( "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/one.php", {contentVar: "cv"},function(data)
```